# Exception 'java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have this error in my onCreate. Any ideas what this means and how I rectify it?

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mistakenly imported `java.sql.SQLException` instead of `android.database.SQLException`.